# Docker Compose Issue : Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set and connection refused

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, hibernate, spring-cloud

I have a problem about running docker-compose file through this command (`docker-compose up -d`).

After running the command, I noticed that 3 services (**advertisement service, user service and lastly report service**) cannot run. It throws an error when I try to see logs in each services through this command (`docker logs <container-id>`)

Here is the error : `org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set`

When I run **other services** (eureka server, api-gateway and management service), I got **connection refused** error.

How can I fix it?

Here is my project link : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootMicroservices)

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  database:
    container_name: mysql-database
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3366:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      #MYSQL_DATABASE: "springbootuser"
      MYSQL_USER: "springmicroserviceuser"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "111111"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "111111"
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "database"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
      timeout: 20s
      retries: 10

  configserver:
    image: configserver
    container_name: configServer
    build:
      context: ./configserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9191:9191"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "configserver"

  eurekaserver:
    image: eurekaserver
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    build:
      context: ./discoveryserver
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "eurekaserver"


  gatewayserver:
    image: gatewayserver
    ports:
      - "8600:8600"
    build:
      context: ./api-gateway
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      PROFILE: "default"
      SERVER_PORT: "8600"
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      EUREKASERVER_URI: "http://eurekaserver:8761/eureka/"
      EUREKASERVER_PORT: "8761"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
      eurekaserver:
        condition: service_started
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "gateway"

  userservice:
    image: user-service
    build:
      context: ./user-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://database:3366/springbootuser?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: "springmicroserviceuser"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: "111111"
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: "update"
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - backend

  managementservice:
    image: management-service
    build:
      context: ./management-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
    depends_on:
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9002:9002"
    networks:
      - backend

  advertisementservice:
    image: advertisement-service
    build:
      context: ./advertisement-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://database:3366/springbootadvertisement?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: "springmicroserviceuser"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: "111111"
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: "update"
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9001:9001"
    networks:
      - backend


  reportservice:
    image: report-service
    build:
      context: ./report-service
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      CONFIGSERVER_URI: "http://configserver:9191"
      CONFIGSERVER_PORT: "9191"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: "jdbc:mysql://database:3366/springbootreport?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&serverTimezone=Turkey"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: "springmicroserviceuser"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: "111111"
      SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO: "update"
    depends_on:
      database:
        condition: service_healthy
      configserver:
        condition: service_started
    ports:
      - "9003:9003"
    networks:
      - backend

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:18.0.2
    environment:
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN=admin
      - KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
    ports:
      - "8181:8080"
    networks:
      backend:
        aliases:
          - "keycloak"
    command:
      - start-dev

  rabbitmq:
    image: "rabbitmq:3-management"
    container_name: "rmq3"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "rabbitmq"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "123456"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"

networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge


volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: Do you have this 'spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect' in the application.properties? I think this is your problem

Comment: @TwisteMisted I tried to use it but I still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Add a spring application json to your environment

```
SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON: '{
        "spring.datasource.url"  : "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:$MYSQLDB_DOCKER_PORT/$MYSQLDB_DATABASE?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false",
        "spring.datasource.username" : "$MYSQLDB_USER",
        "spring.datasource.password" : "$MYSQLDB_ROOT_PASSWORD",
        "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" :"org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect",
        "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto" : "update"
      }'
```

Ensure the database service is running

```
docker compose exec database mysql -u root -p
```

create a new user,allow access from anywhere(%) and grant the necessary permissions to it

```
CREATE USER 'springmicroserviceuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '111111';
CREATE USER 'springmicroserviceuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '111111';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'springmicroserviceuser'@'localhost';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'springmicroserviceuser'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```